# Ghosts 'n' Goblins / Ghouls 'n' Ghosts - why?

Tags: nes, snes

I recall that as a kid I saw the same game with two titles: Ghosts 'n' Goblins, and Ghouls 'n' Ghosts. There may have been others (anyone?)

I'd like to know why there were different names for the same title. Was it a copyright issue as we say in Europe for StarFox / Lylat Wars? Possibly the same case for Contra / Probotector (unless it was a name change to go with the robots as Germany did not like humans killing humans hence the character change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghouls 'n Ghosts was a sequel to Ghosts 'n Goblins as stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghouls_'n_Ghosts).

The game play was pretty much the same. There have been others the game series are as follows:

Ghosts 'n Goblins, Gouls 'n Ghosts, Super Ghouls 'n Ghosts, Makaimura for WonderSwan, Ultimate Ghosts 'n Goblins, and Ghosts 'n Goblins: Gold Knights I && II.

Comment: One other confusing thing is that the first stage of every game in the series uses the same music.  You can [hear how it changed between games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6ZkRDgKoaw).